# How can I track IPs to block malicious users?

Tags: php, databases, ip, algorithm

TL;DR: I want to know should I store both REMOTE-ADDRESS and X-FORWARDED-FOR or either REMOTE-ADDRESS or X-FORWARDED-FOR?

Details...

Here is a few theories to get user's IP

**Theory1:** If you don't use a load balancer, use `REMOTE_ADDR`. If you use a load balancer, use whatever it uses. In 99% of cases that appears to be `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`. So:

```
function get_ip_address(){
    $id = '';
    if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; 
    else
        $ip = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ip;
}
```

**Theory2:** There is some other HTTP header information *(ie. `$_SERVER['HTTP_...]`)* which might be containing the IP. So:

```
function get_ip_address(){
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip){
                $ip = trim($ip); // just to be safe
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Theory3:** Storing both one of `$_SERVER['HTTP_...]` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. So there is two variables:

```
function get_ip_address(){
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED') as $key){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true){
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip2){
                $ip2 = trim($ip2); // just to be safe
                if (filter_var($ip2, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false){
                    $ip1 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                    return array($ip2, ip1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Well honestly I'm confused a little bit. How many column *(in the database)* do I need to store the user's IP? I mean should I store both `REMOTE_ADDR` and a `HTTP_...`? Or just one of them?

Actually I have a query which inserts the user's IP per each page loading in the database. So that query will be executed every time before loading of the page. Surely an `INSERT` query *(everytime for each request, and each user)* has a cost. So I don't want it be useless. I mean I want to store a correct/real IP  or at least I want to do the best work which is possible to detect the user's IP * .

<sup>* When an user uses a proxy like HSS then detecting him would be impossible. That's why I said "at least".</sup>

Ok well, which theory is the best?

Comment: Those theories, as you call them, depend on your software installation.  Is that server behind a proxy or what?  In any case, have you checked the different information available when you access the site remotely to see what is actually there?

Comment: @JuliePelletier *"Is that server behind a proxy"*, what server? My website's server?

Comment: That was indeed the question.  But following the second part of my comment gives you a direct answer.  `var_dump($_SERVER);` and look at what it shows when accessed from the outside.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Well currently I'm on local ..

Comment: hm this questions point eludes me somewhat still it just sounds more like a data storing / programming question, if you are asking best thing to store in order to block the malicious users I would recomend you do some research into: deeper browser fingerprinting, fail2ban at network level, and delay tactics such as captcha and other known methods

Comment: here here on the idea that this shouldn't be hand-rolled, not that it's impossible, just that someone else has already figured out all this mess and solutions are available,.

Comment: pseudocode would be much easier to follow in your question (or perhaps code is unnecessary altogether) - it sounds like you need to capture all those IPs, but you need to know the ***hierarchy*** so that you can determine which IP is most likely to be the real client.

Comment: I also agree that doing this at the network level not the app level is what you want - fail2ban is great.  App level logic would need to understand (and be kept in sync with) network configuration. That sounds terrible to maintain

Answer (score 1):

You need to know which proxy servers you trust, and which headers to trust (if any) for each of them.

For example, you know your load balancer uses [`X-FORWARDED-FOR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) so you can trust the rightmost value that is supplied to your web server in this header.

Your load balancer will also need to know which IPs to trust. For example, it may trust [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) private IPs. You may also want it to trust certain public IPs if, well... if you trust them.

When trusting them, you would probably want to remove them from the chain of IPs that are candidates for storage.

As soon as you hit the first untrusted IP in the chain, then you should store that as the remote IP for the connection. The reason is because anyone can set `X-FORWARDED-FOR` within their HTTP request. If this REMOTE_ADDR is not in your trusted list for `X-FORWARDED-FOR` then you have no reason to trust the header.

This may be complicated if you are trusting arbitrary internet servers with different trusted headers for each.

The above is a generic approach for finding the actual connection that is requesting your page. However, if you are trying to track malicious users you may just want to gather any IP in any header as well as REMOTE_ADDR and then store multiple IPs for each connection. Then if they start doing anything "bad" on your system, you can add a black mark against all of those IPs.

Once so many black marks have been awarded, your system could start blocking connections with that IP in either REMOTE_ADDR or an IP HTTP header. You need to be aware though that a malicious user may try to blacklist other IPs in a denial of service attack. Therefore you are back to my first description of only trusting certain hosts.

Of course, a determined malicious user will always switch hosts when they feel the need to attack your system. e.g. by Tor, by VPN services or via their botnet. It's a tricky thing to accomplish so you may wish to consider other methods of blocking malicious users - e.g. forcing them to sign up with an account before using your system which is verified by SMS. This adds a high enough barrier to block all but the most determined of malicious users.